# Logout user on refresh and close of browser

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working in project using angular, i want to logout the user when user click on close button or refresh button. Below is the code

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
      document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function logData() {
          console.log(document.visibilityState)
        if (document.visibilityState == "hidden") {
          alert("hello")
         navigator.sendBeacon('logout');
        }
      });
    })
```

The problem is when user switches to some other tab in browser, this code executes and user logged out.

I researched on google and find beforeunlod event, but most of the answers saying its not working on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

For refresh (or closing the tab, or closing the browser) we could listen for `window:beforeunload` to trigger logout. For a button it would be a simple `(click)` listener event. The onbeforeunload property of the WindowEventHandlers mixin is the event handler for processing beforeunload events. These events fire when a window is about to unload its resources. At this point, the document is still visible and the event is still cancelable.

```js
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  unloadHandler(event) {
     alert("logging out now...")
     navigator.sendBeacon('logout');
  }
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#examples